# Show data from a hash-table into a select box

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

A have a hash-table with countries in it like this:

```
@countries = {'United States' => 'US', 'France' => 'FR'}
```

and I use the following code to display it in a select box:

```
<%= select_tag 'countries', 
            options_for_select(@countries.to_a) %>
```

Now when it saves data in my table I got in my row US, UK...and so on, now the problem is when I want to output data, so instead of US I would like to output 'United States' I use:

```
<%=h @countries[@offer.from_country] %>
```

But the first hash-table cannot work and I have to reverse the order and use:

```
@countries = {'US' => 'United States', 'FR' => 'France'}
```

Any ideas on how to have the same hash-table for both displaying the data in the select box, and then on the show page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `invert` on your hash. It exchanges keys and values:

```
{:a => '1', :b => '2'}.invert
=> {"1"=>:a, "2"=>:b}
```

Your example:

```
<%=h @countries.invert[@offer.from_country] %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the value attribute of the `<option>` tag to the short country names and the text between the tags to the full country names as shown in the [FormOptionsHelper documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).

Then the returned value is the short country name, but the user sees the full name in the menu.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with an array instead of a hash. This has the advantage that your options will always display in the sequence you place them in your array.

```
@countries = [['United States', 'US'], ['France', 'FR']]
```

Then your select_tag uses the array:

```
<%= select_tag 'countries', options_for_select(@countries) %>
```

And to output the data you can use Array#[rassoc](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/rassoc):

```
<%=h @countries.rassoc(@offer.from_country)[0] %>
```